# Ubuntu installations

Tags: dual-boot

I have win 8.1 preinstalled.I installed  ubuntu  in a drive.but during the booting it is not asking which os is to boot and autometically win is booting.please help me.I am using hp laptop with preinstalled win 8.1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go to the BIOS settings by pressing the escape key and then selecting BIOS (options may vary with firmwares). From there, find the boot devices in UEFI mode (legacy would be disabled by default). Select OS boot manager and hit enter key and bring up ubuntu by either pressing F5 or F6 (explained at the side of the screen) and press F10 twice and save settings and exit.

Comment: why it is not showing install ubuntu alongside?? during installation it ask me to install boot loader code into a partition and to select type BIOS reserved.why??

Comment: With the new gpt partitioning instead of MBR(msdos) partitioning you need either a bios_grub partition for BIOS booting or an efi partition for UEFI booting.

Comment: While booting Ubuntu from DVD or pendrive, what do you see? A black screen with four options or something else?

Comment: so what should I do??

Comment: if I boot from hard disk den only ubuntu is being on but if it is selected os boot manager then win is being on.and my wifi is not working.what to do??means i hv to change boot order each time it is booting and if it selected the hard disk then win boot manager is not showing in the list.only showing win recovery.what should I do??

Comment: @EkPoshlaBristi - you've already accepted this answer.  If you have another question please ask it by clicking the "New Question" button.

Comment: I have a package named smplayer.tar.bz2
how to install this package in ubuntu??pls help me

Comment: @EkPoshlaBristi: Please visit the [Ask Ubuntu Tour](http://askubuntu.com/tour) to better understand how this site works, as it is quite different from a forum...